# Setting signal handler for any signal in C

Tags: c, posix

I'm studying C signals and I'm having trouble with an exercise that requires to write a program which sends back any signal it receives from a process back to the sender process.
I thought about using the function `signal()` or the function `sigaction()`, but they ask you to specify the signum, and I would need them to handle EVERY signal my program receives.
Is there any way to do so without calling the `sigaction()` for every signal number?
Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: [sigaction](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) only takes one signal as an argument, but you could presumably just write a loop through all the signals and set their handlers to all be the same. However, note that you will not be able to handle `SIGKILL`.

Comment: Are you writing the other process, too? If so, write it so that it only sends one type of signal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't specify what OS you are using but this is simple on POSIX systems.  I can't speak to Windows.

The call you want is [sigwaitinfo](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigtimedwait.html).

You need to block all signals and then use `sigwaitinfo` to process any received signals synchronously.  Sigwaitinfo's return code is the signal received and when you pass a non-null siginfo_t struct as the second parameter you get the same information you would get from a signal handler returning a siginfo_t structure, including the pid of the sending process.  Take the received signal and pid and use `kill` to send the signal back to the originating process.  Make sure you aren't sending the signal to *yourself* before calling `kill` lest you end up in a loop of sending and receiving a signal to yourself.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define errExit(msg) do {perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);} while (0)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    siginfo_t signalInfo;
    sigset_t  allSignals;

    printf("echo pid = %d\n", getpid());

    // block every signal but SIGKILL & SIGSTOP which can't be blocked
    sigfillset(&allSignals);

    if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &allSignals, NULL) == -1)
        errExit("sigprocmask");

    while(1)
    {
        // accept signals until SIGTERM delivered
        int sig = sigwaitinfo(&allSignals, &signalInfo);

        if (sig == -1)
            errExit("sigwaitinfo");

        if (sig == SIGTERM)
        {
            printf("buh-bye\n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

        printf("echo received signal %s (%d) from pid = %d\n", strsignal(sig), sig, signalInfo.si_pid);

        /*** NOT doing this for testing because it will kill the sending shell

        // echo signal back to sender but not to yourself
        // which would be stupid and lead to an endless loop

        if (signalInfo.si_pid != getpid())
            kill(signalInfo.si_pid, sig);

       ***/
    }
}
```

**TEST**

--- terminal 1 ---

```
//current shell's pid
> echo $$
7646
//send signals after starting echo pgm in another terminal
> kill -SIGUSR1 7754
> kill -SIGUSR2 7754
> kill -SIGTERM 7754
```

--- terminal 2 ---

```
> echosig 
echo pid = 7754
echo received signal User defined signal 1 (10) from pid = 7646
echo received signal User defined signal 2 (12) from pid = 7646
buh-bye
```